# Counter Values Are Not Changing, MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab and I am having an issue where two counters in my code do not change value.

```
 fid = fopen('results.txt', 'wt');
 counter1 = 0;
 counter2 = 3;
 for i=1:size(res_t,1)
     counter1 = counter1 + 1;
     if(counter2 == 3)
         fprintf(fid, '%f ', res_t.time(:,:)); % first column i need the time
         counter2 = 0;
     end
     fprintf(fid, '%f ', res_t.data(:,:)');
     if(counter1 == 3)
         fprintf(fid, '\n'); %after it writes all 3 X,Y,Z i want to change line
         counter1 = 0;
     end
     counter2 = counter2 + 1;
 end
 fclose (fid);
```

When run, the values of `counter1` & `counter2` do not change, which means they never meet the If statement conditions. My output file is a file which contains: column 1: time values, columns 2-4: X, Y, Z coordinates respectively.

For example:

```
Time1     X1     Y1     Z1
Time2     X2     Y2     Z2
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `res_t`? Use [the debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html). Step through your code and see what it's doing so you can identify the problem.

Comment: res_t is just a matrix which contains the X, Y, Z values. I want to pass these values in a txt file. but i m sure sth is wrong with the counters, but i cant see it!

Comment: What is the size of res_t and what data type is it?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `size(res_t, 1)` returns 1, which would mean your loop only executes once. `rest_t` looks like a struct containing a single element.

Also, what do you mean by "compiled"?  If you are simply running your code in the matlab environment, then it is interpreted, not compiled.

Comment: the compiled word came from the edit that was done to my question .. not my fault

Comment: res_t is an array having 9 rows and 3 columns, and i want to do the for loop 9 times. how can i get this "9" value in order to run the for-loop?

Comment: Is `res_t` a 9x3 array or is it `res_t.data`?

Comment: res_t.data is 9x3 array

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the format of your `res_t` object, but you could just forego the `if` statements altogether with something

```
% Iterate over elements in your time vector
for ii = 1:size(res_t.time, 1)

    % Print time and data to a line, followed by a line feed
    fprintf(fid, "%f  %f  %f  %f\n", res_t.time(ii), res_t.data(ii,1), res_t.data(ii,2), res_t.data(ii,3))

end
```

If `res_t` is a structure with two different arrays in it, `time` and `data`, then you are going to want to iterate through the rows of `res_t.time` (thus the `size(res_t.time, 1)` statement). The above should replace each `%f` with an element from the list of arguments that follows, and then print a new line, so you should get something like:

```
time1  x1  y1  z1
time2  x2  y2  z2
...
```

This assumes that your `res_t.data` array has three columns, X Y Z, and the same number of rows (or more) as your `res_t.time` array.